# Cannot start all the filtered ec2 in Lambda python Boto3

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

```py
instances = ec2.instances.filter(Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['stopped']},{'Name': 'tag:Environment','Values':['Dev']}])
for instance in instances:
    id=instance.id
    ec2.instances.filter(InstanceIds=[id]).start()
    print("Instance ID is started :- "+instance.id)
```

All the filtered Ec2 are priting but only 2 3 ec2 are get powered on.

I need to change setting so my all my filtred ec2 are get power On

Comment: Can you try replacing `ec2.instances.filter(InstanceIds=[id]).start()` with `boto3.resource("ec2").Instance(instance.id).start()`? This should operate on a single instance without the additional fluff of listing + filtering instances. Please also include the code that instantiates `ec2` here. Are there any error messages? (Using `id` as a variable name in Python may lead to unexpected results as that hides a built-in function, maybe try `instance_id`)

Comment: No other errors its returning success :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `start()` on the returned instance:

```py
instances = ec2.instances.filter(Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['stopped']},{'Name': 'tag:Environment','Values':['Dev']}])
for instance in instances:
    instance.start()   # <-- This line changed
    print(f"Instance ID is started: {instance.id}")
```